# Why does Amazon Deals page is not rendering properly?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am playing around with [Python Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) and [Splash Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to test extraction of dynamic content of some websites, and all was games and fun until I tried to get some data from Amazon Deals Page (https://amazon.com/deals). The dynamic div with all the products simply did not render, and i wasn't able to access the data by `Scrapy Shell`.

[image]

Checking the same page at Amazon in dev tools, I get 297  tags:
[image]

When I list all anchor tags rendered by scrapy splash, it never return more than 150  tags, and none of then is a product.

[image]

Maybe I am done something wrong? Or it is some Amazon way to prevent scraping? Is there a viable solution to bypass this if this is the case?